# Jhipster Spring Boot Log setup

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I create app using JHipster. Is there any simple way to configure application to create log files for each separate day ? I tried everything in one file but its getting to big and its not good practice. I did that by adding this part on the end of my server start command :

```
>> console.log &
```

Logback-spring.xml :

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs/log-file.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <Pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <queueSize>512</queueSize>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</appender>


<logger name="javax.activation" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="javax.mail" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="javax.xml.bind" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="com.codahale.metrics" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="com.ryantenney" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="com.sun" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="com.zaxxer" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="io.undertow" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="io.undertow.websockets.jsr" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="org.ehcache" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="org.bson" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.elasticsearch" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.validator" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.web" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.security" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.cache" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.thymeleaf" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.xnio" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="springfox" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="sun.rmi" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="liquibase" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="LiquibaseSchemaResolver" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="sun.rmi.transport" level="WARN"/>

<!-- https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#shutdownHook and https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1090 -->
<shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook"/>

<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
    <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure a `RollingFileAppender` in `logback-spring.xml` rather than using a `ConsoleAppender`. See https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

The logback-spring.xml generated by JHipster contains all the prod configuration, you just have to uncomment it.

```
<!-- The FILE and ASYNC appenders are here as examples for a production configuration -->
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <Pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <queueSize>512</queueSize>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</appender>
<root level="${logging.level.root}">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
</root>
```

Comment: I did this, and when i start server in dev mode from eclipse it created file for today date but its empty all the time

Comment: Let's forget about eclipse, does it work with mvnw or gradlew or running the executable war? And also I thought you were looking for a prod solution not in dev because you question does not make much sense in dev.

Comment: Yes of course just wanted to test. So i builded .war file using maven. I started it and it still create log file but write everything to console. How should i redirect output to log files ?

Comment: The right configuration is commented out in your generated logback-spring.xml you just have to uncomment it https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml#L8-L28 don't forget  the appender-ref

Comment: As you can see in edited comment that is exactly what i did but it still doesn't write anything to log files but in console. Should i start program with some additional command ?

Comment: I can't see the appender-ref on root level in your question  as in my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in your own logback.xml

```
<appender name="dailyRollingFileAppenderError" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>${DEV_HOME}/error.log</File>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <FileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</FileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>


<root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppenderError"/>
</root>
```